# Testing a func to read a specific JSON config file

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, io

I am new to testing in Go and am trying to test a `func` that reads a JSON config file (for Snowflake).

I've read several questions that suggest using an `io.Reader` interface but I can't totally put it altogether on why it makes sense to do so as well as how to do so successfully.

Here is my method:

```
package helpers


import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

type SfConfig struct {
    User      string `json:"user"`
    Password  string `json:"password"`
    Account   string `json:"account"`
    Warehouse string `json:"warehouse"`
    Database  string `json:"database"`
    Schema    string `json:"schema"`
    Role      string `json:"role"`
}

func ReadSnowflakeConfig(fp string) (string, error) {
    var config SfConfig
    file, err := os.Open(fp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Could not open Snowflake credentials file.")
        return "", err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    data, err := io.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Could not read Snowflake credentials file.")
        return "", err
    }
    json.Unmarshal(data, &config)

    // Prepare our snowflake DB connection string
    connString := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s:%s@%s/%s/%s?warehouse=%s&role=%s",
        config.User,
        config.Password,
        config.Account,
        config.Database,
        config.Schema,
        config.Warehouse,
        config.Role,
    )
    return connString, nil
}
```

Actual test.json file:

```
{
    "account": "account",
    "user": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "role": "CRUD_ROLE",
    "warehouse": "WHS",
    "database": "DB",
    "schema": "schema"
}
```

Comment: "I can't totally put it altogether on why it makes sense to do so" - because your production code can call it with a real file from `os.Open`, and your test code can pass in a `bytes.Reader` or `strings.Reader` and pass in the config as a literal value.

Comment: @Adrian so you'd use os.Open() in the calling ```func```? Wouldn't that component need to be tested as well?

Comment: Right. I wouldn't bother testing code that does nothing but call a stdlib function that already has its own tests. I don't need a unit test in my project that just confirms that `os.Open` does what it says on the tin, and I don't want a unit test that interacts with the filesystem if I can possibly avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your func signature to make function to be testable.

Your func should have a bit of abstract of where it takes config, so my suggestion is use something like this

```
func (reader io.Reader) (string, error) {
 ... 
}
```

Or just pass test config file to the method in test, the separate one.